# Time Series Forecasting for Humidity

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have following input values and wants to predict the humidity values for the values present in timestamps list

```
startDate = "2013-01-01"
endDate = "2013-01-01"
knownTimestamps = ['2013-01-01 00:00','2013-01-01 01:00','2013-01-01 02:00','2013-01-01 03:00','2013-01-01 04:00',
               '2013-01-01 05:00','2013-01-01 06:00','2013-01-01 08:00','2013-01-01 10:00','2013-01-01 11:00',
               '2013-01-01 12:00','2013-01-01 13:00','2013-01-01 16:00','2013-01-01 17:00','2013-01-01 18:00',
               '2013-01-01 19:00','2013-01-01 20:00','2013-01-01 21:00','2013-01-01 23:00']
humidity = ['0.62','0.64','0.62','0.63','0.63','0.64','0.63','0.64','0.48','0.46','0.45','0.44','0.46','0.47','0.48','0.49','0.51','0.52','0.52']
timestamps = ['2013-01-01 07:00','2013-01-01 09:00','2013-01-01 14:00','2013-01-01 15:00','2013-01-01 22:00']
```

and I am using following function to predict the humidity values using AR model in python

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
def predictMissingHumidity(startDate, endDate, knownTimestamps, humidity, timestamps):
    data_prediction = pd.DataFrame({'knownTimestamps': knownTimestamps,'humidity': humidity})
    print(data_prediction.head(10))
    history = [float(x) for x in data_prediction.humidity]
    predictions = []
    test = timestamps
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=(2,2,0))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        output = model_fit.forecast()
        yhat = output[0]
        predictions.append(float(yhat))
    print(predictions)
    return predictions
```

The model predict the same value of humidity for the values in time stamp list.

```
 res = predictMissingHumidity(startDate, endDate, knownTimestamps, humidity, timestamps) 
 print(res)


 output = [0.5287247355700563, 0.5287247355700563, 0.5287247355700563,
 0.5287247355700563, 0.5287247355700563]
```

Can someone help me with where I am going wrong

Comment: I don't see you returning `predictions` in the function or calling the function.

Comment: yes I didn't include that part in the question, I'll make the changes

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks you just repeat same calculation n times where n is len(test). The iteration variable t is never used and all arguments are the same every time.